# How does order of precedence affect a recursive method?

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm interested in learning how the following recursive method handles it's return statement. Using the debugger it seems the method argument gets pushed to the stack. Then upon return the equation is evaluated. In the call tree below how are the values 1, 2, 6, and 24 generated?

```
factorial(5) 
   factorial(4) 
      factorial(3) 
         factorial(2) 
            factorial(1) 
               return 1 
            return 2*1 = 2 
         return 3*2 = 6 
      return 4*6 = 24 
   return 5*24 = 120

  private static int factorial(int x)
    {
        if (x == 1)
            return 1;
        return x * factorial(x - 1);
    }
```

Comment: You've literally shown exactly how they're generated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as C# cares, as if you called any other method. There's no optimizations specific for recursion in C#.

The order of operations is defined in C#, so you always know what's evaluated when. In this case, however, it doesn't really matter - you're just calling a function with an argument and returning the value multiplied. No magic involved.

Don't get too caught up on the internal details of what happens. Arguments aren't really passed through the stack most of the time, especially on 64-bit. It's also possible a tail-call optimization will be performed (not something the C# compiler does right now, but not impossible either) which means no arguments are passed *really* - you reuse the same data location for the data over and over again, similar to rewriting the recursion to use an imperative loop instead.

The debugger does its best to make the code easy to debug. This also makes it *different* from code running outside of the debugger. For example, the lifetime of locals in the debugger will extend to their whole block scope, while outside of the debugger they are no longer guaranteed to exist as soon as you access them the last time. The code is also reordered to preserve the same single-threaded operations while improving performance.

If you want to see the actual x86 code executing, you can run the application outside of the debugger, and invoke it with `Debugger.Launch`/`Debugger.Break` - this will allow you to bypass the debugger simplifications.

In my particular case, the relevant code looks like this:

```
000007FE956204D0  push        rsi  
000007FE956204D1  sub         rsp,20h  
000007FE956204D5  mov         esi,ecx  ; store x
000007FE956204EA  lea         ecx,[rsi-1]  ; pass x - 1 ...
000007FE956204ED  call        000007FE95620080  ; ... to factorial
000007FE956204F2  imul        eax,esi  ; multiply the return value with stored x
000007FE956204F5  add         rsp,20h  
000007FE956204F9  pop         rsi  
000007FE956204FA  ret
```

As you can see, nothing is passed by the stack. Instead, the old value of `rsi`/`esi` is preserved on the stack. With tail-call optimized recursion, even that can be avoided.